# Space at bottom of div containing image

Tags: css

For this fiddle, why is there a space at the bottom of `div#imageDiv`?

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7Knyx/1/)

```
<div>
<div>
<div>
    <img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b6/SIPI_Jelly_Beans_4.1.07.tiff/lossy-page1-256px-SIPI_Jelly_Beans_4.1.07.tiff.jpg" />      
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div id="text"><div id="inner">text goes here</div></div>        

html {
  line-height: 1.5em;
}
#text {
  background-color: grey;
  margin-top:-7px;
}
```

​

​

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Set your image to `img { display: block; }`. And please next time add your code here on SO to prevent link rot and lets us easily review your code here.

Comment: So do inline elements automatically create some 'padding' when inside block level elements? Where can I read up on this, ive tried googeling but im not finding anything relevant. Thanks

Comment: @jdln 1 sec. I'll grab a link to the spec for you :)

Answer (score 1):

Give your image a bottom vertical alignment and the space goes away.

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/7Knyx/10/)**

```
img {
    vertical-align:bottom;
}
```

Comment: @PeterVR - Check your CSS son, "The vertical-align CSS property specifies the vertical alignment of an inline or table-cell element." per https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/vertical-align

Answer (score -1):

you could also margin-top property to achieve that

http://jsfiddle.net/meetravi/7Knyx/14/

P.S Its always great to avoid negative values in css if you are planning to support relatively old browsers

Comment: I consider this a quick and very dirty fix, not an actual answer as to the how and way of the problem...

Comment: Yeah I know its dirty so only I mentioned it creates lot of errors with old browsers...